# How to add a backslash before all . and / in 10.0.1.0/24?

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to escape a subnet to use it as a `sed` regex replacement.

This is what I have so far, missing the search and replacement part.

```sh
echo '10.0.1.0/24' | sed 's///g'
```

Comment: It's much easier to use a different delimiter with sed. `sed 's|10.01.0/24|192.168.15.0/24|`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
sed 's~[./]~\\&~g' <<< '10.0.1.0/24'
```

```
10\.0\.1\.0\/24
```

Or using awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/[.\/]/, "\\\\&")} 1' <<< '10.0.1.0/24'
```

```
10\.0\.1\.0\/24
```